# UserNotifications displays past time (ex: 2 minutes ago)

Tags: ios, iphone, usernotifications

I am fetching some data in the background on a time interval. so the data that comes may be minutes old. 
I want to display the real time in a local "UserNotifications" of the data (ex: 2 minutes ago) not "Now".

I wonder if it's possible.

Thank you

Comment: When do you fire the local notification? Immediately after fetching the data?

Comment: Yes, but I want to display the real time of the data on the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to change this date. iOS always shows the date the notification itself was posted.

If you want the post notifications in real time, you either have to increase the polling frequency, or use push notifications.

Comment: Thank you for you answer that's all what i needed to know